# How to group columns in 1 row and gather information in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr

I have this data.frame:

```
# Variable 1        Variable 2    Business(spec)
# Name Business     Macaco SA     NA
# ID Business       10            NA
# Type Business     Fishing       NA
# Name Business     Simio SA      NA
# ID Business       20            NA
# Type Business     Other         Transport
```

This was a file in excel that I imported to R. Variable 2 is a list of specific type of business. If the type of business is not in the list, in `Business(Spec)` they need to write the type of their business (so this variable can have different values). And i want to sort like this:

```
# Name Business    ID Business    Type Business    Business(spec)
# Macaco SA        10             Fishing          NA
# Simio SA         20             Other            Transport
```

I tried with `pivot_wider(data, names_from = "Variable 1", values_from = "Variable 2")` but it didn't work. How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, i used `pivot_wider`!!

Comment: You have discordant data and no apparent "id" column. However you are getting your data ... complain loudly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can group things together (is it always 3 rows?), then you have a better chance.

I had to munge the data to use it more easily, so variable names and values are slightly different.

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Variable1         Variable2     Business(spec)
Name_Business     Macaco_SA     NA
ID_Business       10            NA
Type_Business     Fishing       NA
Name_Business     Simio_SA      NA
ID_Business       20            NA
Type_Business     Other         Transport")

dat$grp <- cumsum(dat$Variable1 == "Name_Business")
dat
#       Variable1 Variable2 Business.spec. grp
# 1 Name_Business Macaco_SA           <NA>   1
# 2   ID_Business        10           <NA>   1
# 3 Type_Business   Fishing           <NA>   1
# 4 Name_Business  Simio_SA           <NA>   2
# 5   ID_Business        20           <NA>   2
# 6 Type_Business     Other      Transport   2
pivot_wider(dat, id_cols = "grp", names_from = "Variable1", values_from = "Variable2")
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#     grp Name_Business ID_Business Type_Business
#   <int> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>        
# 1     1 Macaco_SA     10          Fishing      
# 2     2 Simio_SA      20          Other
```

This makes an assumption that `"Name_Business"` is always the first within a grouping of rows, and that everything immediately after it is related to that row.